# Is there a way to examine table lock logs?

Tags: sql-server

I'm seeing some timeout errors with respect to deadlocks, specifically:

```
Transaction (Process ID 161) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

It's intermittent, and while I have an idea what's causing the issue, I'd like to investigate and verify before I put too much time and effort into it.

Is there a way to view the logs surrounding these types of errors to see what queries the transaction was running, and/or what tables were being locked at the time?

Since it's intermittent, it's difficult for me to catch the problem in the act.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deadlocks are always intermittent and unpredictible.

By default, SQL Server doesn't keep any historical information about deadlocks which could help in investigating their cause. You have to prepare upfront if you want to collect this information.

You have basically two options: setting a trace flag 1222 and examinig information in error log, or starting up a profiler session capturing deadlock graph event. Both will provide information on deadlocked queries and the resource they were deadlocked on.